# Bookmark icons in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I know that when you are making a bookmark in nautilus the icon of the bookmark is the same as the folders icon but the problem is when i restart my pc the bookmark icon remains default until clicking on it. How can i fix this?

I'm providing two screenshots made after reboot:

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/512565/how-to-reset-nautilus-launcher-icon-shortcuts-to-default/512953#512953)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that there is some trick around Nautilus, since I was able to reproduce the same behavior in Debian. But, just in case, try to re-set the icon for the Dropbox folder:

1. Right click the directory/folder.
2. Click Properties.
3. Click the "Icon" besides the `Name:`.
4. Look for the desired icon or hit Revert.

The changes should be immediate, but in your case a log-in/off might be necessary to verify that everything is in order.

Comment: i can change the icon for the folder. it changes immediately but when i log off and log in back the icon in the bookmarks remains default! until i enter the dropbox folder, after that it changes to the folders new icon

Comment: @Rain you tried another icon? Just for test case, create another user and check it out. If everything fails you should report as bug in LaunchPad.

Comment: Hi, Nautilus in Ubuntu 16.10 doesn't show the custom icon in the bookmark area...any hint ?