# How to restore Nautilus Launcher icon quicklist to default

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, launcher, quicklists

After an update I ended up with this:

[image: Files quicklist]

How can I add the default Files quicklist options which are not bookmarks (Documents, Downloads, Music...)

The same happened to Nautilus when I opened it, but I added the options in `~.config/user-dirs.dirs` but now the Launcher icon is missing this options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default entries, which are added automatically to the `Files` launcher icon (not the ones, mentioned in the `.desktop file`) , are stored in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`, as lines in the format:

```
file:///home/[your_username]/Documents
file:///home/[your_username]/Downloads
```

etc.

I am afraid you will have to re-enter them manually if the file was messed up somehow.

...Or, if you simply want to use *all* the entries in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, you can use the script below :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
home = os.getenv("HOME")
exclude = ["Desktop", "Templates"]

with open(home+"/.config/user-dirs.dirs") as locations:
    homelinks = [item.replace("\n", "").split("$HOME/")[-1][:-1] \
                 for item in locations.readlines() if item.startswith("XDG_")]

with open(home+"/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks", "wt") as bookmarks:
    for item in homelinks:
        if not item in exclude:
            bookmarks.write("file://"+home+"/"+item+"\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

After finished editing the file `user-dirs.dirs` and add these bookmarks (you can use also @JacobVlijm's answer ), you have to run `xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update` to update this file.

Comment: This is better!