# Nautilus column size not shrinking.Also Weird folder instead of Documents

Tags: unity, nautilus

[image: Nautilus fixed column size]

Now no matter what I do, the file manager would not shrink to the left. It will extend to its right but it will not shift even a bit more left that this. Also the Document icon shows the location of some other file instead of showing "Documents". It will however open the "/home/user/Document" directory though instead of being named to some other location.Now since the name of this named location is very large,Nautilus is trying to display its full Name and hence the column size is not reducing. Maybe that is the reason.What shall I do to get back the nautilus to default size and fix the Document error.

**Edit**:
Nevermind I fixed it my editing the ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks file.
Here is the link (read the second answer):
[How do I restore a Places folder I accidentally deleted in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580155/how-do-i-restore-a-places-folder-i-accidentally-deleted-in-nautilus)