# Terminal not showing files (that are there) after Ubuntu updrade

Tags: command-line, 18.04, nautilus, gnome-terminal, filemanager

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.2 LTS and opened up a terminal to find a handful of my home directory contents. Basically only Videos/ and a few files [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvI1R.png). However the files and folders are all still there. Autocomplete does not work if I start typing Documents/, but if I do `ls Documents/` the content is all there.

The files manager also shows other folders in the side tab, which contain all the relevant files, but the home directory is still reduced:[what my file manager looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV05i.png).

Here is the content of `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

User permissions of the visible and invisible content all seem identical.
This is really bizarre:

```
guillermo@guillermo-TECRA-A40-C:~$ ls
gerrit.ods  noise_nuisance_log.docx  print.pdf  ranking_Cg_rank_0001_to_00-1.pdf  scripts  v6_BSM_Coupling.tar.gz  Videos
guillermo@guillermo-TECRA-A40-C:~$ mkdir Pictures
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Pictures’: File exists
```

Any ideas? :_(

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

```
 echo $HOME
/home/guillermo
```

Comment: Can you check whether the root filesystem (or at least, where /tmp is mounted) is full and/or non-writeable? Autocomplete relies on the shell being able to create a temporary file in /tmp, and if that filesystem is full or non-writeable it won't work. 'df /tmp' from the command line, or 'echo Hello > tmp/text' will both give a clue. Not sure if that is the whole situation, but it might be part of what is going on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of command `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Comment: Thanks @ColinB , everything with /tmp seems fine, I can write to the filesystem, and indeed ls works fine in other directories.

Comment: Hi @steeldriver , thanks for the response. I added the content you suggested, but it looks like this is not the issue since the folders are there. Maybe I should have mentioned that my home directory is encrypted, so could there be some wonkyness going on in the mount?

Comment: Your `ls` command doesn't reveal permissions. Use `ll` command instead.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I already checked permissions, everything is normal.

Comment: I just created a directory in my $HOME and it won't shown up with ls, but I can still cd into it and create files etc. Maneuvering my filesystem with dired in emacs I see the same thing.

Comment: Update Your question with `alias ls` and `echo $HOME` output and `ls -la`.

Comment: Hi @MichalPrzybylowicz, thanks, I added the alias and echoed my home, I already have `ls -la` info in the attached image: `alias ll='ls -alF'`

Comment: Have You rebooted Your PC after upgrade? These folders should be automatically created after reboot... or run this command `xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update` as per this answer : https://askubuntu.com/questions/580155/how-do-i-restore-a-places-folder-i-accidentally-deleted-in-nautilus

Comment: Hi@MichalPrzybylowicz, yes I rebooted, several times now. All my folders are still there from the filesystem before I upgrade Ubuntu, they where not created again.