# Nautilus launcher icon no longer contains Places and Bookmarks on right-click (14.04.02)

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher

I had `nautilus` crash (`apport` caught it, so I guess I can still locate the logs if it might help) the other day, and afterwards the icon on the side launcher opened a new 'identical' `nautilus` icon whenever I clicked it, so I unpinned it and pinned the new one instead.

However, the new icon doesn't respond with a list of my Places and Bookmarks when I right-click it. Instead it only has "Files" or "Unlock from Launcher", and a list of open `nautilus` windows if there are any.

Following advice from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/512596/142526) I looked at my `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` file, but it still contains all of my Places and Bookmarks. They are also visible inside any `nautilus` window.

Anyone knows what might be the cause of this behavior? This is a fairly fresh install of Trusty 14.04.02.
(I pretty much exhausted my expertise by restarting Ubuntu and searching Google+AskUbuntu. BTW if my question is a duplicate of [this older one](https://askubuntu.com/q/524686/142526), my apologies. I couldn't be sure if the causes were the same, plus it has no comments or answers so I figured it's okay to post this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus is represented by multiple `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`. Most likely, your current "new" icon is the `nautilus-folder-handler.desktop` -file.

The one you need is `nautilus.desktop`.

#### What to do

- Just navigate to the directory `/usr/share/applications`
- Look for the file `nautilus.desktop`
- Drag the file to the launcher
- Log out and back in

No need to say that you need to *unpin* the wrong nautilus icon...

Comment: Great. If you don't mind a follow-up: how come when I put "nautilus" in the Dash it only finds the one result, when I have two separate `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` executing `nautilus` (with different parameters, it seems)?
It looks like whatever `.desktop` is currently (or was last) pinned will be opened when I pick that result in Dash.

Comment: That's a good one! In "normal" situations, it should show multiple files, since they are differently named, calling the same application. There must be a blind spot on my mind why I cannot tell you why. I'll try to figure it out. It is not what is currently pinned, since if you pin both, still only one shows up in Dash. Then I tried killing nautilus (`pkill nautilus`); still the same...

Comment: The ones that don't show up have a`NoDisplay=true` line in the .desktop

Comment: @doug WOW, how on earth could I miss that. Speaking about blind spot :). Thanks for the clearing up!

Comment: @JonathanY. see doug's comment above...