# Nautilus: No custom icons in the bookmark area

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus, icons

It seems since at least 17.04. The bookmark menu doesn't show the icon assigned to a folder but instead just shows a generic folder icon like so:

[image]

Now both of these folder show up in the actual file view like so:
[image]

It seems this wasn't always the case [Bookmark icons in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276802/bookmark-icons-in-nautilus)

Why doesn't nautilus do this anymore? Its a great feature and I would like to get it back.
I'm running 18.04.

Comment: Modern Nautilus is very limited. Use Caja or Nemo instead :)